# The stdin of chained commands and commands in command substitution

Tags: bash, zsh

Let me present my findings first and put my questions at the end. (1) applies to `zsh` only and (2), (3) apply to both `zsh` and `bash`.

#### 1. stdin of command substitution

```
ls | echo $(cat)
ls | { echo $(cat) }
```

The first one prints **`cat: -: Input/output error`**; while the second one produces the output of `ls`.

#### 2. chained commands after pipe

```
ls | { head -n1; cat}
ls | { read a; cat}
```

The first command doest work properly. `cat` encounters `EOF` and directly exits. But the second form works: the first line is read into `a` and `cat` gets the rest of them.

#### 3. mixed stdin

```
ls | { python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv)' $(head -n1) }
ls | { python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv); print(input())' $(head -n1) }
```

Inside the `{}` in the first line, the command is to print the cmdline arguments; in the second form, the command also reads a line from `stdin`.

The first command can run successfully while the second form throws due to that `input()` reads the `EOF`.

#### My questions are:

1. (as in section 1) What is the difference between the form with `{}` and without ?
2. (as in section 2) Is it possible for the `head` and `cat` to read the same `stdin` sequentially? How can the second form succeed while the first form fails?
3. (as in section 3) How is the `stdin` of the command in a command substitution connected to the stdin of the original command (`echo` here). Who reads first? And how to make the `stdin` kept open so that both commands (`python` and `head`) can read the same `stdin` sequentially?

Comment: `head -n1; cat` are two separate commands. There you use `head` within a *braced-group* (not command substitution) which receives the output of `ls` on `stdin`, and then you effectively call `cat` with no arguments -- what do you expect will happen?

Comment: `head` to get the first line, and then `cat` to get the remaining lines. Perhaps the `chained` word confused you. I didn't know the correct word before. Should it be `grouped`?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be grouped. For a *pipeline* (e.g. `foo | bar | baz`) each pipe connects the `stdout` of the prior command with `stdin` of the next. Putting a line termination `';'` between the commands is the same thing as having the two separate lines in a script. There is no connection between the two. If you want the first file `ls -1 | head -n1`. If you want all but the first, then `ls -1 | tail -n+2`.

Comment: @david: in `produce_data |  { head -n1; cat}`, I'd expect `head` to read the beginning of the input, perhaps 8k or so, output the first line and quit. `cat` with no arguments will read whatever is left in stdin and print it to stdout. I'd be expect the same if I executed a function `head_plus (){ head -n1; cat; }` In the that sense, the braced commands do have a connection, because they read the same as nput. Unfortunately, `head` is a greedy bugger and reads a lot more than one line, so there is less input left over for cat. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I tried this `seq 1 xxx | { head -n1; cat; }` with different `xxx`, `cat` starts to print from line 1861, and `seq 1 1861 | wc ` tells it is indeed 8198 bytes. Howerver `seq 1 2000 | { head -n1; head -n1; }` only outputs one line, the second `head` gets nothing.

Comment: @LiuSha: Not quite, if you look closely. Really, that's just bad luck; it happens that the buffer ends right at the end of line 1860, just before the newline character. So the second `head -n1` returns the first line it sees, which is a blank line. If you look at the output closely, you'll see the blank line. Or try `seq 1 1863 | { head -n1; head -n2; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not taking input buffering into account and it explains most of your observations.

`head` reads several kilobytes of input each time it needs data, which makes it much more efficient. So it is likely that it will read all of stdin before any other process has a chance to. That's obvious in case 2, where the execution order is perhaps clearer.

If input were coming from a regular file, `head` could seek back to the end of the lines it used before terminating. But since a pipe is not seekable, it cannot do that. If you use "here-strings" -- the `<<<` syntax, then stdin will turn out to be seekable because here-strings are implemented using a temporary file. I don't know if you can rely on that fact, though.

`read` does not buffer input, at least not beyond the current line (and even then, only if it has no other line end delimiter specified on the command line). It carefully only reads what it needs precisely because it is generally used in a context where its input comes from a pipe and seeking wouldn't be possible. That's extremely useful -- so much so that the fact that it works is almost invisible -- but it's also one of the reasons shell scripting can be painfully slow.

You can see this more clearly by sending enough data into the pipe to satisfy `head`'s initial read. Try this, for example:

```
seq 1 10000 | { head -n1; head -n2; }
```

(I changed the second `head` to `head -n2` because the first `head` happens to leave `stdin` positioned exactly at the end of a line, so that the second `head` sees a blank line as the first line.)

The other thing you need to understand is what command substitution does, and when it does it. Command substitution reads the entire output of a command and inserts it into the command line. That happens even before the command has been identified, never mind started execution.

Consider the following little snippet:

```
$(printf %cc%co e h) hello, world
```

It should be clear from that that the command substitution is fully performed before the echo utility (or builtin) is started.

Your first scenario triggers an oddity of `zsh` which is explained by Stéphane Chazelas in [this answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338162/24557). Effectively, `zsh` does the command substitution *before* the pipeline is set up, so `cat` is reading from the main zsh's standard input. (Stéphane explains why this is and how it leads to an EIO error. Although I think it is dependent on the precise zsh configuration and option settings, since on my default zsh install, it just locks up my terminal. At some point I'll have to figure out why.) If you use braces, then the redirection is set up before the command substitution is performed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I got your points for the last two questions. But then is it possible to achieve the shared stdin for the `head` and `cat`? For the last paragraph, I don't understand this sentence "a shell might do the command line substitution during the execution of the enclosed command", although I know the facts you mentioned after it.

Comment: What you mentioned for question 2 and 3 is correct. But I also find this link [INPUT FILES](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) which mentioned the concept of `seekable files`. The standard utilities like `head` should respect the correct file offset when dealing with seekable files. So I tried the following `{ head -n1; echo "==="; head -n1 } <<< $(ls)` and it worked!

Comment: @LiuSha: OK, with the help of a post on [unix.se] I tried to provide some hints about what is going on with zsh in your first section. I also made some minor improvements to the answer text. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks very much for all your time to answer the questions. Now everything is explained. I will need to take some look into zsh’s pipe and redirection. From the post your referenced, it seams it behaves quite differently from bash.

Comment: @liuSha: I'm not a zsh user, which is why it's badly configured on my current machine (I had a working installation before I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, but I hardly ever used it.) Stéphane says it has to do with zsh's redirection multiplexing, so I'd start by looking at that.